# nested state in angular js gives TypeError

Tags: angularjs

I have two states, one abstract parent and the other child. Nothing fancy,

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
      .state('navBar', {
        url: "/navBar",
       abstract: true,
     views: {
          'navBarView': {
        templateUrl: "templates/navigationBar.html",
         controller:'AppCtrl'
       }
     }


      })
       .state('navBar.orderReceive', {
        url: "/orderReceive",
        views: {
          'orderReceiveView': {
            templateUrl: "templates/OrderReceiveChoice.html"


          }
        }
      })

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector) {
           var $state = $injector.get('$state');
           $state.go('navBar.orderReceive');

        });
```

controller:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope','$state','$stateParams','$rootScope', function($scope,$state,$stateParams,$rootScope){
             }]);
```

I get TypeRrror: Can not read property controller of undefined. I have the  controller that in fact is getting initialized. What does really look wrong with it?

Also, If I remove the nested state, it works fine without any errors.But I need nested state.
Error looks like this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined
    at IonicModule.controller.self.update (ionic.bundle.js:51695)
    at IonicModule.controller.self.beforeEnter (ionic.bundle.js:52135)
    at IonicModule.controller.self.beforeEnter (ionic.bundle.js:54079)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$emit (ionic.bundle.js:24919)
    at Object.IonicModule.factory.ionicViewSwitcher.create.switcher.emit (ionic.bundle.js:50634)
    at Object.IonicModule.factory.ionicViewSwitcher.create.switcher.transition (ionic.bundle.js:50492)
    at ionic.bundle.js:52121
    at ionic.bundle.js:50370
    at Object.IonicModule.factory.ionicViewSwitcher.create.switcher.render (ionic.bundle.js:50459)
    at Object.IonicModule.factory.ionicViewSwitcher.create.switcher.init (ionic.bundle.js:50369)
```

Comment: can you please edit your question with controller code,it'll be good ?

Comment: Updated. Though I get this error even if I remove the controller. It has something to do with state only. May be its expecting controller to be defined in nested state. I tried to do that as well but no help

Comment: You have a problem somewhere but not in the code you post.

Comment: @Michelem:Not with the nested state either? I do not have any more code. Only the html

Comment: Look, there isn't any error: http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/sot6mvj4/